# How to remove parts of a string between a certain character in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, replace

I need a function to chop-off parts of a string between slashes(/).

```
Dim str As String = "Hi my /unnecessary string 1/ name /unnecessary string 2/ is Bob /unnecessary string 3/"
'code to remove unnecessary parts of the string goes here
MsgBox(str)
```

Take note that `str` is an input from the user, I just used this code snippet to present a neat explanation. Thank you.

Comment: String.Split() may be usefull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Split to find each string between the `/` character and show every other one:

```
    Dim str As String = "Hi my /unnecessary string 1/ name /unnecessary string 2/ is Bob /unnecessary string 3/"
    Dim parts As String() = str.Split("/"c)
    For i = 0 To parts.Count - 1 Step 2
        Debug.WriteLine(parts(i).Trim)
    Next
```

Or you could use Regex to remove text between forward slashes:

```
    Dim pattern = "/.*?/"
    Dim myString = Regex.Replace(str, pattern, "")
    Debug.WriteLine(myString)
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this helped a lot.